# How do I remove a CircleCI check from a GitHub repo?

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, circleci

Recently my company has gone with Jenkins as its CI/CD solution, after trying a number of options.  I'd like to disable checks from the other CI packages.

I've deleted the SSH key and web hooks from Circle CI, but it still marks the build check as "failed" on the merge requests (it's only partially implemented.)

I'd like there not to be a CircleCI check at all.  How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

From within CircleCI, click unfollow and then remove.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without going into CircleCI?

Comment: Deleting all of the web apps and integration for CircleCI within GitHub. This should work fine, but without doing it on CircleCI's end, there's the slight possibility that the webhooks get re-added at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Going to a user|organisation profile Settings, then "Third-party application" can also help to remove Circle-CI.

Answer (score 0):

This approach worked for me:
https://discuss.circleci.com/t/remove-projects-we-accidentally-added/27766

You create a script with your token and group name, then create a file with your repo name in it and run the script with the file as a param.